# Are the outcomes of the maximum shifts function fixed regardless of our choice of axiomatic system?

Tags: busy-beaver

It is known that there is a $748$-state Turing machine that halts if and only if $\mathsf{ZF}$ is inconsistent. So by Gödel's second incompleteness, $\mathsf{ZF}$ cannot find what $S(748)$ exactly is, where $S$ is the maximum shifts function (Also known as the "Frantic Frog").

I'm rather confused by this fact. As $S$ is well-defined, that should mean that regardless of what axiomatic system we use, the exact value of $S(748)$ always stays the same. We just need a stronger axiomatic system to find $S(748)$, like $\mathsf{ZFC}$, $\mathsf{ZFC+CH}$, or $\mathsf{ZFC+(V=L)}$.

If $\mathsf{ZFC}$ and $\mathsf{ZF¬C}$ entailed $S(748)$ to be different numbers, since Axiom of Choice is independent to $\mathsf{ZF}$, it would be concluded that $\mathsf{ZF}$ was inconsistent at the first place. So far, is my understanding correct?

Comment: There is a group with 2 elements, and another group with 3 elements. Are the group axioms inconsistent?

Comment: @YuvalFilmus No. Would you state your argument more explicitly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting but slightly confusing thoughts, indeed.

Let us tread water slowly and cautiously.

- Suppose $\mathsf{ZF}$ is inconsistent.

  - Suppose we continue to use $\mathsf{ZF}$. Every proposition becomes trivially true. $S(748)$ can be any number. (That 748-state Turing machine will halt. That does not mean much though, since every proposition is true.)
  - Otherwise, suppose we choose another axiom system. Which one should we use? What will happen over there? That should be the story of another question, of a very different nature possibly, although an answer to that question might well be the wanted answer of this question as well.
- Suppose $\mathsf{ZF}$ is consistent. However, we cannot prove that (within $\mathsf{ZF}$ or any enclosing axiomatic systems) even if that is true.

  - $S(748)$ is well-defined, (which can be proved). That means, whatever relatively consistent extension of $\mathsf{ZF}$ we would choose to use later, such as $\mathsf{ZFC}$ or $\mathsf{ZFC+CH}$, $S(748)$ will remain the same.
  - That 748-state Turing machine will never halt. (However, this cannot be proved.)

---

"$\mathsf{ZF}$ cannot find what $S(748)$ exactly is". Yes, in the sense that, when $\mathsf{ZF}$ is indeed consistent, we can never be sure that 748-state Turing machine will never halt.

"We just need a stronger axiomatic system to find $S(748)$, like $\mathsf{ZFC}$, $\mathsf{ZFC+CH}$, or $\mathsf{ZFC+(V=L)}$." As explained above, the problem is not about whether $\mathsf{ZF}$ is strong enough. The problem is whether $\mathsf{ZF}$ is consistent, a question that signifies a part of the intrinsic boundary of our knowledge. It could be consistent, which we could believe willingly and happily but we cannot prove.  It could be inconsistent, an example of which could elude us before the end of the universe.

"If $\mathsf{ZFC}$ and $\mathsf{ZF¬C}$ entailed $S(748)$ to be different numbers, since Axiom of Choice is independent to $\mathsf{ZF}$, it would be concluded that $\mathsf{ZF}$ was inconsistent at the first place". That statement is correct.

I would like to emphasize that overwhelmingly most of mathematicians/computer scientists work with the implicit or explicit assumption that $\mathsf{ZF}$ is consistent. Once the distrous possibility of $\mathsf{ZF}$ being inconsistent is introduced into the discussion, be careful and slow to avoid confusion.

Comment: The answer to the question in the title is, mostly, yes, since the maximum shifts function can be defined with Peano axioms plus first-order logic.